# html table: uncaught TypeError: Cannot set properties of null (setting 'innerHTML')

Tags: javascript, html

[my code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GtqBw.png)I've been stuck on the last statement for the whole day. Unfortunately, I haven't been able to find a solution to the problem yet. I have tested my code using console.log() and everything seems to work well except for the last line. Could you please help me figure out what's going wrong? Thank you!

I tried use console.log() to test where was going well. The expected results: Write a program that reads the Student Exam Records.  The program must output an HTML table, with a row for each student who had an exam score with a grade of “A”.  An “A” is defined for this program as a score that is greater than or equal to 90. The table will be preceded by an HTML header tag identifying the table.

Comment: Please use the code snippet to show the code, not the images.

Comment: please don't include code as an image.
check to see if your outputTable is actually visible inside the function you're trying to update the innerHTML in

Answer (score 0):

please declare

let outputTable = document.getElementById("outputTable");

in global scope and use it in the functions this will resolve the error.

I hope it will